# jQuery animated number counter from zero to a certain number returned in a PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a script to animate a number from zero to a certain number obtained from a PHP file. But doesn't works.

This is my code:

**JQUERY**

```
(function($){
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function (){
        $("#tasksCompleted").load("https://workhub.atexto.com/main/tasksCompleted.php").fadeIn("slow");
    },
    3000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds

  jQuery({ Counter: 200000 }).animate({ Counter: $("#tasksCompleted").text() }, {
    duration: 8000,
    easing: "swing",
    step: function () {
        $("#tasksCompleted").text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="tasksCompleted"></span>
```

Here is the demo (dont's work): 
https://jsfiddle.net/rwf707Lp/

Comment: in your jsfiddle you have not included jquery. I think you need to include.

Comment: Yeah https://jsfiddle.net/rwf707Lp/1/ works.

Comment: Thank you, but don't works. Runs the animation backwards from 200,000 to zero and then shows the PHP number without animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
I changed a coupled things from my first answer...

The trick, to show an "achievement counter" will be to count from zero to the number obtained via ajax on page load.

Then the interval to constantly check for an updated achievement has to check if the quite long onload animation had finished.

If not finished the initial counting... Just let it finish! And wait for the next inteval iteration.

Then... If the obtained number is different from the number "before ajax", count!

The speed now depends on the number form the ressource speed to increase.

I think that is closer to what you wish...
;)

```js
(function($){
  console.clear();
  var number_beforeAjax;
  var number_afterAjax;

  var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function (){
      number_beforeAjax = parseInt( $("#tasksCompleted").text().replace(",","") );
      console.log("number_beforeAjax: "+number_beforeAjax);
    
      $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/45614889/ressource.php",
        success: function(data){
          $("#numberFromAjax").html(data);
          counter();
        }
      });   //$("#numberFromAjax").getJSON("https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/45614889/ressource.php",counter());
    },
    3000); // refresh every 3000 milliseconds

  // A separate function to call as a load callback
  function counter(){

    // Just to see what was loaded via ajax.
    var loaded = $("#numberFromAjax").text();
    console.log("loaded: "+loaded);

    // Number loaded via ajax parsed as integer.
    number_afterAjax = parseInt( $("#numberFromAjax").text().replace(",","") );
    console.log("number_afterAjax: "+number_afterAjax);

    // If the numbers before and after ajax are different
    if(number_beforeAjax != number_afterAjax && !isNaN(number_afterAjax) ) {
      
      counterSpeed = 5000;
      // Faster if the difference isn't much
      if(number_afterAjax-number_beforeAjax<20){
        counterSpeed = 2900;
      }
      // Set the start number to zero on 1st iteration
      var startNumber;
      if(isNaN(number_beforeAjax)){
        startNumber = 0;
      }else{
        startNumber = number_beforeAjax;
      }

      // Counter!
      jQuery({ Counter: startNumber }).animate({ Counter: number_afterAjax }, {
        duration: counterSpeed,
        easing: "swing",
        step: function () {
          $("#tasksCompleted").text(Math.ceil(this.Counter).toLocaleString());
        }
      });
    }

    // Just a console.log
    if(number_beforeAjax == number_afterAjax && !isNaN(number_afterAjax)){
      console.log("Request revealed no change.")
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#numberFromAjax{
   display:none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="tasksCompleted"></span><br>
<span id="numberFromAjax"></span>
```

**Got to wait 3 seconds** for the first interval to start in this snippet...
When you'll see "Request revealed no change.", just wait a little for the ressource to increment.

**EDIT**
[`.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) re-adds the coma on the number to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. But how to take the last value showed in the HTML as the initial value for the counter in each interval?

Comment: *«last value showed»* when? After the end of an interval? Just before `.load()` (to allow faster refresh maybe)?

Comment: after the end of each interval to refresh the counter in the way that make the count not from zero

Comment: something like that:
if (number == 0)
      var initial = 300000;
    else
      var initial = number; jQuery({ Counter: initial }).animate({ Counter: number }, {...

Comment: mmm... I tried something [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BdZoey?editors=1111)... But the effect is the counter "slows", since the duration stays the same but the count range changed. And when you number is reached. It looks stopped. -- But maybe it's what you want.

Comment: I fixed the "slowing", using another span to receive the data from Ajax. But that is a strange counter. ;)

Comment: Here is exactly what  I need: https://cloudconvert.com
In the footer, here: "We've converted" counter "files".
I dived into the code but unfortunately I don't understand it:

Comment: Here is the code:https://cloudconvert.com/min/serve/g/d8dd18854bffbd8bf66936b3a476ace5/lm/1502105182
Lines 69 and 70

Comment: Nope... That is jQuery v2.2.4. Ok, I see what you want. Hold on.

Comment: I posted something closer to what you want ;)

Comment: Amazing! Absolute thank you. One more little thing: how to put again the "," in the number that shows in the front-end?

Comment: The coma can be added using [`.toLocaleString() `](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). See edit. ;)

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. The problem with that solution is that you will can't change the start number. To see my point try putting 300000

Comment: This was nice:       if(number_afterAjax-number_beforeAjax<20){
        counterSpeed = 2900;

Comment: start number can be changed... That is the one to start with on page load. `startNumber = 0;` You can use 300000 instead of 0.

Comment: And 2900 is, in fact, 100 below the 3000 of the interval loop. ;) That is to have the exact timing to increment to the given value before next interval.

Comment: The problem with that solution is when local string uses dot not comma. The solution is: number_beforeAjax = parseInt( $("#tasksCompleted").text().replace(",","").replace(".",""));

Comment: Well, I wrote this solution based on some requirement. Sure if the number given isn't formatted the same, you will find issue. Like if the number is in word (ex: two thousand forty three), it will be another thing. What are trying to do here by searching all possible issues ?

Comment: Only trying to contribute to OS community. Thank you again, was a pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine you just missed to import Jquery lib ,

see below  snippet :

```js
(function($){
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function (){
        $("#tasksCompleted").load("https://workhub.atexto.com/main/tasksCompleted.php").fadeIn("slow");
    },
    3000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds

  jQuery({ Counter: 200000 }).animate({ Counter: $("#tasksCompleted").text() }, {
    duration: 8000,
    easing: "swing",
    step: function () {
        $("#tasksCompleted").text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="tasksCompleted"></span>
```

Comment: Don't works. Runs the animation backwards from 200,000 to zero and then shows the PHP number without animation